# How to play video contionously in iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, cocoa-touch

I am using MPMoviePlayerController but I am getting the issue is that its repeats only two times but I have to repeat it continuously how to do that please any one suggest me better way for it.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:outPutUrl];

    player.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);
    player.repeatMode = MPMovieRepeatModeOne;

    [player setShouldAutoplay:YES];
    [player prepareToPlay];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(moviePlayerDidFinish:)
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                               object:player];
    [player setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleNone];

    [self.imgView addSubview:player.view];

    [player play];
}
-(void)moviePlayerDidFinish:(NSNotification *)note
{
    if (note.object == player)
    {
        NSLog(@"this is note%@",note.object);

        NSInteger reason = [[note.userInfo objectForKey:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishReasonUserInfoKey] integerValue];

        if (reason == MPMovieFinishReasonPlaybackEnded)
        {
            [player play];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i have past outPutUrl path already its running two times but not running third time.

Comment: once paste that outPutUrl here..

Comment: this is out put urlfile://localhost/private/var/mobile/Applications/C4E432A2-6B60-4092-B339-8B9516B95687/tmp/output.mov

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"drvo_hd_final-1" ofType:@"mp4"]]];
    player.view.frame = CGRectMake(20, 20, 280, 200);
    player.repeatMode = MPMovieRepeatModeOne;
    [player setShouldAutoplay:YES];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(moviePlayerDidFinish:)  name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:player];
    [player setControlStyle:MPMovieControlModeDefault];
    [self.view addSubview:player.view];
    [player prepareToPlay];
}

- (void)moviePlayerDidFinish:(NSNotification *)note
{
    if (note.object == player)
    {
        NSLog(@"this is note%@",note.object);
        NSInteger reason = [[note.userInfo objectForKey:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishReasonUserInfoKey] integerValue];
        if (reason == MPMovieFinishReasonPlaybackEnded)
        {
            [player prepareToPlay];
        }
    }
}
```

**This is working for me and playing continuously.....**

Comment: but i tried this ,its also not working what should i do please help me.

Comment: it's working for me dude.. okay you have copied this one and pasted and also then you didn't get...

Comment: just see the edited answer and paste my code and check and let me know

Comment: i just copy past the same code but i don't know why its not working